# How to create 3 way data binding between angularFire 0.5.0 and latest ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ng-grid, angularfire

angularFire $bind method can be found here : http://angularfire.com/flatdoc.html and latest ng-grid can be found here : http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

I tried the simplest possible solution but it didnt work :

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',

    rowTemplate:'<div ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex(), \'color\': \'rgb(248, 248, 248)\',\'background\': \'none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7)\' }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>',
    headerRowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{ height: col.headerRowHeight,\'color\': \'rgb(248, 248, 248)\',\'background\': \'none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7)\'  }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngHeaderCell" ng-header-cell></div>',
    multiSelect: false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name',editableCellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />'},
                 {field:'age', displayName:'Age',editableCellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />'}]


};
$scope.myData.$bind($scope,'gridData');
```

and then

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-model="gridData"></div>
```

I mean, is that even possible? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Before we get into the how, let's review a couple important details:

1. Firebase and angularFire both work in objects and ngGrid wants arrays (we'll need a filter)
2. angularFire is a great wrapper for common use cases, but not the only way to access Firebase
3. There is a feature in Firebase which automatically converts sequential, numeric IDs to arrays, which we can take advantage of.

So with those details in mind, there are two easy approaches.

**Leveraging Firebase array emulation**

Assuming our data is a straightforward array and that we won't be deleting keys (if the ids aren't sequential our array becomes an object), then we can just reference the data right from Firebase.

Here's [a fiddle demonstrating the following example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/eTak7/):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngGrid']);
var fb = new Firebase('https://nggrid-example.firebaseio-demo.com/');

app.controller('ctrl', function($timeout, $scope) {
    $scope.myData = [];
    fb.on('value', function(snap) {
        // force a compile since we aren't in $digest
        $timeout(function() {
           $scope.myData = snap.val();
        });
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

**Using a filter on angularFire data**

However, if we want to stick with pure angularFire, or our data is going to be editing in real-time by multiple users (which would wreak havoc on an array), we can filter the data into an array using the orderByPriority filter.

Here's [a fiddle demonstrating the following example](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/TywxU/5/):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngGrid']);
var fb = new Firebase('https://nggrid-example.firebaseio-demo.com/');

app.controller('ctrl', function($firebase, $scope, orderByPriorityFilter) {
    $scope.data = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.myData = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.$watchCollection('data', function() {
       $scope.myData = orderByPriorityFilter($scope.data); 
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
});
```

Comment: But this is not 3 way binding yet, because when I edit the cell in ng-grid and then click out of the cell, value should update in firebase too :) Works perfectly though, its just my updated values dont update in firebase :(

Comment: if I add `ng-blur="updateEntity(col, row)"` to my `editableCellTemplate:` and then I add this : `$scope.updateEntity = function(col,row){ console.log(row.entity); console.log(col.field); };` console logs out perfectly, but I also get this error: `Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($id) in property 'targetScope'. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"` @kato

Comment: Solved myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941102/how-to-make-angularfire-send-ng-grid-onblur-changes-to-firebase-automatically/20958369#20958369