# how to make angularfire send ng-grid onBlur changes to firebase automatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ng-grid, angularfire

This is a followup question from here: [How to create 3 way data binding between angularFire 0.5.0 and latest ng-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929801/how-to-create-3-way-data-binding-between-angularfire-0-5-0-and-latest-ng-grid) where [Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394010/kato) nicely provided a solution:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase', 'ngGrid']);
var fb = new Firebase('https://nggrid-example.firebaseio-demo.com/');

app.controller('ctrl', function($firebase, $scope, orderByPriorityFilter) {
    $scope.data = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.myData = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.$watchCollection('data', function() {
       $scope.myData = orderByPriorityFilter($scope.data); 
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData',enableCellEditOnFocus: true };
});
```

However, this solution puts data nicely into my ng-grid, but if I edit any of the cells, changes are not automatically applied to firebase.

I have tried various ways, but none of them seem to work :

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit',function(value){
                    $scope.data.$set(value);
                });
```

Nope.

I have also tried angularFire event handlers such as `.$on("change")`

Tables I am creating will be edited by multiple users in real time.

Kato solution nicely converts firebase objects into arrays, but then I also need to find a way how to convert edited values in ng-grid to objects so I can store them in firebase on the fly.

if I add `ng-blur="updateEntity(col, row)"` to my `editableCellTemplate:` and then I add this :

```
$scope.updateEntity = function(col,row){
                    console.log(row.entity);
                    console.log(col.field);
                };
```

console logs out perfectly, but I also get this error:

`Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($id) in property 'targetScope'. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"`

P.S. I get this error only if I have this as well:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit',function(value){
                    $scope.data.$set(value);
                });
```

If I dont have this piece, then nothing is being saved to firebase (or atleast tried).

Comment: $scope.data.$set(value) is failing probably because some of the data has characters like ".", "#" etc. which are not allowed as key names in Firebase.

Comment: Yes, I know :) Its because angularFire uses $id instead of id. `$scope.updateEntity = function(col,row){
                console.log(row.entity.id); //logs undefined
                console.log(row.entity.$id); //logs out id
                
                };` but I havent found solution around it yet...

Comment: You can't set $scope.myData to $firebase(ref) and to orderByPriorityFilter(...). It's going to be constantly overwritten as both an angularFire instance, and then an array of data, ad nauseam.

Comment: $scope.attributes.$update($scope.attributes) works around the key-name error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution !!

All that is needed to be done is adding this : `ng-blur="updateEntity(col, row)"` to `editableCellTemplate:` and then this:

```
$scope.updateEntity = function(col,row){
                    $scope.data.$save(row.entity.$id);
                };
```

Now this: `$scope.data.$set(row.entity.$id);` will not work, because it will replace THE WHOLE OF YOUR FIREBASE DATABASE with id (so a number, for example "0"). So always test it before using it! :)

Tadaaaa ! 3 way data binding!

Comment: Great solution; that looks like a way to get it done! Keep in mind that there's a bit of magic here; you are changing data in $scope.data by changing the values in $scope.myData (they share the same child object pointers, even though one is an array and the other an object). Literally, ngGrid updates the array, which accidentally updates the object as well. Also, make sure you fix the error I mentioned above with $scope.myData; that's going to cause all sorts of unpredictable behaviors.

Comment: $scope.myData; error fixed :) Now its : `$scope.data = $firebase(ref);
                $scope.myData = [];`

Comment: I have te same problem. It is in fact only 2.5 way binding instead of 3 way binding. You have to do the final save to the server yourself!